# Rails validates_uniqueness_of with unless validation on self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validates-uniqueness-of

I'm using rails for authentication and want to validate the uniqueness of a username, unless the other username was set up as a temporary account.

Example:
We set up a user account that has name: "buddy" with email: "placeholder@email.com"

A user comes and creates an account.  We want the user to be able to user the name "buddy" if the only other buddy account is associated with email: "placehoder@gmail.com".

Bascially I want to do something along the lines of:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, unless: User.where(name: :name).first.email.include?("placeholder@email.com")
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a Proc to the unless: option, like so...

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, unless: Proc.new { |user| User.where(name: user.name).first && User.where(name: user.name.first.email.include?(user.email) }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Slight modifications, but set me on the correct path:

validates_uniqueness_of :name, unless: Proc.new { |user| User.where(name: user.name).first && User.where(name: user.name).first.email.include?("placeholder@gmail.com")}

Comment: Ah, wow, `"placeholder@gmail.com"` is a literal!  I didn't grasp that first read.  Anyway, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, conditions: -> {where.not(email: "placeholder@email.com")}
```

This will generate a query like

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users"
  WHERE ("users"."name" = 'buddy') AND
        ("users"."email" != 'placeholder@email.com')
  LIMIT 1
```